# Как Laravel livewire скрыть список, если не активен input?

Tags: laravel, laravel5, laravel-5.6, livewire

Использую livewire в Laravel 7

```
<input type="text" wire:model="query">
    <ul>
        @foreach($tops as $top)
            <li>
                <p>
                    {{ $top->Name }}
                </p>
            </li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
```

Как скрыть список, пока нет фокуса на инпут. Отобразить список, когда есть фокус и вводятся значения и опять скрыть, когда фокус с инпут пропадает?